# how do I monitor data from serial port and have certain data act as a flag in Python

Tags: python, serial-port, arduino, pyserial

I am working on a project for work and I am stuck on a part where I need to monitor a serial line and listen for certain words using python

so the setup is that we have a automated RAM testing machine that tests RAM one module at a time and interacts with software that came with the machine via serial. The software that came with the RAM tester is for monitoring/configuring the testing process, it also displays all of the information from the SPD chip from each module. while the RAM tester was running I ran a serial port monitoring program and I was able to see the same information that it displays in the software. The data I'm interested in is the speed of the RAM and the pass/fail result, both of which I was able to find in the data I monitored coming over the serial line. There are only 5 different speeds of RAM that we test, so I was hoping to have python monitor the serial line and wait for the speed of the RAM and the pass/fail results to come across. once python detects the speed of the RAM, and if it passes, I will have python write to an Arduino, and the Arduino will control a conveyor belt that will sort the ram by speed.

my idea is to have a variable for each of the RAM speeds and set the variables to 0. when python detects the RAM speed from the serial line it will set the corresponding variable to 1. then when the test is over the results, either pass or fail, will come over the serial line. this is where I am going to try to use a if statement. I imagine it would look something like this:

```
if PC-6400 == 1 and ser.read() == pass    
    ser.write(PC-6400)                   #serial write to the arduino
```

I know the use of the ser.read() == pass is incorrect and that's where I'm stuck. I do not know how to use a ser.read() function to look for certain words. I need it to look for the ram speed (in this case its PC-6400) and the word pass but I have not been successful in getting it to find either. I am currently suck in is getting python to detect the RAM speed so it can change the value of the variable. would it be something close to this?

```
if ser.read() == PC-6400
    PC-6400 = 1
```

This whole thing is a bit difficult for me to explain and I hope it all makes sense, I thank you in advance if anyone can give me some advice on how to get this going. I am pretty new to python and this is the most adventurous project I have worked on using python so far.

Comment: You probably want `if PC-6400 == 1 and ser.read() == 'pass'`. Without the quotes you are trying to compare the data read from serial with the Python `pass` statement.

Comment: thank you for your advice because I would have defiantly had issues with that when I get to that point, but I am actually stuck a bit before that point in the code. I'm just trying to find a way to get ser.read() to only look for the words "PC-6400" on the serial line. I revised my question so hopefully it makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a bit confused, but here's a very basic example to hopefully get you started.

This will read from a serial port. It will attempt to read 512 bytes (which just means 512 characters from a string). If 512 bytes aren't available then it will wait forever, so make sure you set a timeout when you made the serial connection.

```
return_str = ser.read(size = 512)
```

You can also see how many bytes are waiting to be read:

```
print "num bytes available = ", ser.inWaiting()
```

Once you have a string, you can check words within the string:

```
if "PASS" in return_str:
    print "the module passed!"

if "PC-6400" in return_str:
    print "module type is PC-6400"
```

To do something similar, but with variables:

```
# the name pass is reserved
pass_flag = "PASS"

PC6400 = 0

if pass_flag in return_str and "PC-6400" in return_str:
    PC6400 = 1
```

Keep in mind that you it is possible to read part of a line if you are too quick. You can add delays by using timeouts or the `time.sleep()` function. You might also find you need to wait for a couple of seconds after initiating the connection as the arduino resets when you connect. This will give it time to reset before you try and read/write.

Comment: alright thanks ill try messing with return_str and see if I can get something going. here is a sample of the data coming over the serial line. if you look closely you can see where the RAM test starts, then you can see the time counting up as it is testing, and finally you can see the info about the RAM and the word PASS signifying the test is over. its not pretty but its all there.

Comment: The sample is all where?

Comment: sorry it's too big to fit, it's over 2000 characters.

Comment: Waiting for Handler Start ....Åþ....[ Esc. ]Åþe.ÅþE.ÅþE.Åþ.*..L001: wk_addr                    [00:00]Åþ....[Cancel]ÅþA'Åþ.*..L001: wk_data                    [00:00]Åþ....[Cancel]ÅþA'Åþ.*..L001: Mats                             [00:01]Åþ....[Cancel]ÅþA'Åþ...![00:02]Åþ...![00:02]Åþ...![00:03]Åþ...![00:03]Åþ...![00:03]Åþ...![00:04]Åþ...![00:05]Åþ...![00:05]Åþ...![00:06]Åþ...![00:06]Åþ...![00:07]Åþ...![00:07]Åþ...![00:08]Åþ...![00:09]Åþ...![00:09]Åþ...![00:10]Åþ.*..L001: Mar_X                      [00:10]Åþ....[Cancel]ÅþA'Åþ...![00:11]Åþ...![00:11]Åþ...![00:12]Åþ...![00:12]

Comment: Åþ...![00:12]Åþ...![00:13]Åþ...![00:14]Åþ...![00:14]Åþ...![00:15]Åþ...![00:15]Åþ...![00:16]Åþ...![00:17]Åþ...![00:17]Åþ...![00:18]Åþ...![00:18]Åþ...![00:19]Åþ...![00:19]Åþ...![00:20]Åþ...![00:20]Åþ...![00:21]Åþ.*..L001: Mar_C                      [00:21]Åþ....[Cancel]ÅþA'Åþ...![00:22]Åþ...![00:22]Åþ...![00:23]Åþ...![00:23]Åþ...![00:24]Åþ...![00:24]Åþ...![00:25]Åþ...![00:25]Åþ...![00:26]Åþ...![00:26]Åþ...![00:27]Åþ...![00:28]Åþ...![00:28]Åþ...![00:29]Åþ...![00:29]Åþ...![00:30]Åþ...![00:31]Åþ...![00:31]Åþ...![00:32]Åþ...![00:32]Åþ...![00:32]Åþ...![00:33]Åþ...![00:34]

Comment: Åþ...![00:34]Åþ...![00:35]Åþ...![00:35]Åþ...![00:36]Åþ...![00:37]Åþ...![00:37]Åþ...![00:37]Åþ...![00:38]Åþ...![00:39]Åþ.*..L001: Mar_Y                      [00:39]Åþ....[Cancel]ÅþA'Åþ...![00:39]Åþ...![00:40]Åþ...![00:40]Åþ...![00:41]Åþ...![00:41]Åþ...![00:42]Åþ...![00:42]Åþ...![00:43]Åþ...![00:43]Åþ...![00:44]Åþ...![00:44]Åþ...![00:45]Åþ...![00:45]Åþ...![00:46]Åþ...![00:46]Åþ...![00:47]Åþ...![00:47]Åþ...![00:48]Åþ...![00:48]Åþ...![00:49]Åþ...![00:49]Åþ...![00:50]Åþ...![00:50]Åþ...![00:51]Åþ...![00:51]Åþ...![00:52]Åþ...![00:52]Åþ...![00:53]

Comment: Åþe.Åþ}...ÅþE.Åþa¡ÅþD.Åþ"0.Module..: DDR2 256Mx72 2GB 2R(8)@2x400MHZ 1.8V.Åþ"...(Tested at 2x400MHz).Åþ".Addr.(rowxcol.).: 14 x 10.Åþ".Data (rankxbit).:  2 x 72.Åþ".Internal Banks.:  8.Åþ""Burst.: Mode=Sequential, Length=8.Åþ"*AC parameters.: CL=5, AL=0, Trcd=5, Trp=5.Åþ".S/N from SPD.: a128fab5.Åþ".Test Loop #.: 1.Åþ"..## PASS:   Loop 1 ##.Åþ"..Elapsed Time.: 00:00:53.456.Åþa¢Åþc.............H..ÿÿÿÿ"ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ...s-(U.?€.....".. Åþ@.ÅþE.Åþ....**PASS - L001 @2x400MHZÅþ...![00:53]Åþ....Transmit Results ...Åþa¡ÅþD.Åþ"0.Module..: DDR2 256Mx72 2GB 2R(8)@2x400MHZ

Comment: 1.8V.Åþ"...(Tested at 2x400MHz).Åþ".Addr.(rowxcol.).: 14 x 10.Åþ".Data (rankxbit).:  2 x 72.Åþ".Internal Banks.:  8.Åþ""Burst.: Mode=Sequential, Length=8.Åþ"*AC parameters.: CL=5, AL=0, Trcd=5, Trp=5.Åþ".S/N from SPD.: .Åþ".Test Loop #.: 1.Åþ"..## PASS:   Loop 1 ##.Åþ"..Elapsed Time.: 00:00:53.456.Åþa¢Åþ@.Åþ. ..

Comment: like I said, it's not pretty...  this is a sample of the data from one module being tested. all the data I'm interested in is at the end all the data in the middle is just the timer counting up on the software. if you look at the end of the data you will see ## PASS  and 2x400MHZ.  those are the 2 words I would like to write to the arduino.